# DDQN cannot solve Tic Tac Toe

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, dqn

I am trying to solve Tic Tac Toe with a DDQN approach since a long time now. It took me a while to fill my holes in knowledge, but now my code seems fine. However, I am unsure about how to train the agent, since it is a two player game. Currently, I let the agent play with **X** and let **O** be played by a random player, who makes random but legal moves, while the agent can also play illegal moves and gets a negative reward for that. The step function looks as follows:

```
def step(self, action):
    reward = 0.
    info = None
    if self.state[action] != 0:  # illegal move
        reward = -1.
        self.done = True
        return self.state, reward, self.done, info
    self.state[action] = self.turn  # make move
    self.turn = -self.turn
    self.state[-1] = self.turn  # update last state, which refers to the turn
    if self.is_winner():  # check for win
        reward = 1.0
        self.done = True
    elif self.state.count(0) == 0:  # check for draw
        reward = 1.0
        self.done = True
        info = 'draw'
    elif self.state.count(0) == 1: # check for draw in final move of the opponent
        final_action = self.state.index(0)
        self.state[final_action] == self.turn
        if not self.is_winner():
            reward = 1.0
            info = 'draw'
            self.done = True
    return self.state, reward, self.done, info
```

So a positive reward is given, if the agent wins, draws or if he plays a move, that results in a draw in the next move played by the random player.

Unfortunately, the DDQN doesn't converge. I cannot get an average reward of more than about 0.5. To follow training progress, I let the agent play 1000 games every 1000 games with the current parameters and an epsilon of 0.01. Sometimes after finding a good strategy, the average suddenly negative, so it seems to be pretty unstable aswell.

My hyperparameters are as follows:

```
lr = < 0.001 (I trained many)
memory size = 100.000
target network update rate = 1000
epsilon start = 1.0, epsilon end = 0.1
batch size = 512
```

Does anyone have tips on what I can do better? How many training epochs are to be expected for a simple game such as Tic Tac Toe?

Comment: Please post a MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Your memory size is only 100. Maybe you meant 100_000 instead of 100.000?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i experienced same issues, but after some tries i was able to train DDQN for 3x3, 4x4 and some good results was also observed on 5x5 game boards. Check my code here https://github.com/hreso110100/RL-Tic_tac_toe